# Big O of fixed size array linear search

Tags: algorithm, big-o, computer-science

`const a = Array.apply(null, Array(50)).map((x, i) => i);`

This array will never be changed, it will always contain 50 elements.

Would `a.includes(x)` (linear search) be O(n) OR O(50) OR technically O(50) but we call is O(n)

Comment: O(50) is the same as O(1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be O(N) because N implies that there is a certain variable that is affecting the runtime. Since the array is always 50 elements it will always loop through 50 times instead of a variable amount of times- so that function is O(50), which we usually simplify to call O(1)- which represents all constant-time functions.

Answer (score 1):

Big-O characterizes *functions*. So the answer is that you get to choose. If you define the function you're trying to characterize as something like "worst case number of comparisons as a function of n, the number of elements," then the answer is O(n). In your case n happens to be 50, but of someone else solved the same problem for different values of n, the worst case run time would vary linearly with input size.  If you define it as "number of comparisons to search a fixed-length array", then the answer is O(1).  O(50) is exactly the same set of functions as O(1).